# Initialize start-up applications in certain workspaces?

Tags: workspaces, startup-applications

Is it possible to set start-up applications to initialize in certain workspaces? I'd like to not have to manually distribute my start-up applications across my numerous workspaces every time I boot up my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 .

Any Help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , thats possible using `gdevilspie` ( GUI of `devilspie`) :

Open Terminal and type the following coommand :

```
sudo apt-get install gdevilspie
```

Now open gdevilspie with (Alt + F2, gdevilspie, Enter).

Click start daemon and automatically on login .

Example here is **Skype** ( you should set it to run on startup ) :

[image]

**devilspie** [Here](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)

[image]

[image]

Now restart daemon and try .

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: hope it fits your needs , any time my friend

Comment: This looks great, but it crashes on my 13.10, and [the same happens on 13.04 too](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151162&s=0cfffffe3f050f8801a2e4e65bde0dfd). There's also [an Arch bug report](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gdevilspie/). I'll see if there's a more recent version of `gDevilspie` than stock Ubuntu provides.

Comment: Ah,the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/issues/list) looks abandoned, but someone has provided a patch, and someone else reports that it works.

Comment: also run `sudo apt-get install devilspie`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, this can also be done with CompizConfig (and in fact, if your workspaces are generated by CompizConfig, then the devilspie solution doesn't seem to work):

> CompizConfig > Window Management > Place Windows > Fixed Window Placement > Windows with Fixed Viewport

Make sure that "Place Windows" is enabled (CompizConfig > Window Management).

Answer (score 0):

Install wmctrl

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

And create a script (in this example thunderbird on the second workspace (`-t 1`)):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
(thunderbird &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Thunderbird` -t 1"
```

To know your application name on wmctrl you can view it by taping on your terminal :

```
wmctrl -l
```

And replace it with the correct name in the script.

Be carrefull with the capital letter ("Thunderbird" not "thunderbird") !!

Other example with firefox on the 3d workspace (`-t 2`):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/sh
(firefox &)  & sleep 5 && 
sh -c "wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l | grep Firefox` -t 2"
```

Work on Debain 10 with Cinnamon. But should work for all